# Where i should store a UI configuration for each user

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

i developed the aspnet mvc app with knockoutjs and i make the grid with data. that grid have the configuration like: which column should be visible and it size also grid can generate filters on json which handle on server and making remoting sorting\filtering\ordering and users can make the own presets of filters and settings. question, where the store it? i store it in cookies and on mssql but
i heard that is bad practice. how to be
P.S trying to avoid a lot of requests to the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use local or session storage, described [here](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp).

localStorage usage example:

```
// Store localStorage.setItem("lastname", "Smith"); // Retrieve 
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("lastname");
```

sessionStorage usage example:

```
if (sessionStorage.clickcount) {
    sessionStorage.clickcount = Number(sessionStorage.clickcount) + 1;
} else {
    sessionStorage.clickcount = 1;
}
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "You have clicked the button " +
sessionStorage.clickcount + " time(s) in this session.";
```